# Is `BoundedSourceQueue` from `Source.queue` ok with concurrent producers?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

`Source.queue` recently added an [overload which specializes to `OverflowStrategy.dropNew` and avoids the async mechanism](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/queue.html#description-boundedsourcequeue-html). The result of materializing this is a [`BoundedSourceQueue[T]`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.6/akka/stream/BoundedSourceQueue.html) (compared to [`SourceQueueWithComplete[T]`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.6/akka/stream/scaladsl/SourceQueueWithComplete.html) in the older version). The docs for the `SourceQueueWithComplete` variants of `Source.queue` make it clear that the materialized queues should be used by any number of concurrent producers:

> The materialized SourceQueue may be used by up to maxConcurrentOffers concurrent producers.

The docs for the `BoundedSourceQueue`  don't say anything about this. **Is this constraint lifted for `BoundedSourceQueue`? Can it be used by any number of concurrent producers?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, the `SourceQueueWithComplete` variant doesn't have the `maxConcurrentOffers` restriction if `OverflowStrategy.dropNew` is in effect.

However, because the result of offering an element to the `SourceQueueWithComplete` is communicated asynchronously, that does mean that if a producer produces faster than it handles the future, it may overwhelm memory.  Asynchrony removes backpressure, unless some other mechanism reintroduces it, after all.

Because when the strategy is `dropNew`, it's possible to know immediately that the element was dropped, the result of offering can be communicated synchronously (i.e. blocking the producer until it handles/throws away the result).  This allows there to be arbitrarily many producers without OOM risk.  For this reason if using the `dropNew` strategy, the `BoundedSourceQueue` version is recommended (i.e. only use the `SourceQueueWithComplete` if some other strategy is being used), with the recommendation becoming stronger as load becomes higher.

Yes, the number of running threads is the limit for the number of concurrent producers to the `BoundedSourceQueue` variant.